# PDE with Partial derivatives to different variables $u_{x}+u_{y}-u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve for $u$ assuming $u=u(x,y)$

$u_x+u_y-u=0$

I'm stuck here. I know how to solve it if there is only $u_x$ or $u_y$ or if there is no $u$ but since there is all 3, I'm stuck.

In my notes I have a similar problem of $3u_x-2u_y+u=x$, we choose to let $z=y, w=3z+2x$ and ended up with

$u_x=V_wW_x+V_zZ_x=2V_w$

$u_y=V_wW_y+V_zZ_y=3V_w+V_z$

I am not sure what the purpose of introducing 2 new variables is or where the $V$ came from. If someone knows the purpose or if someone has another way to solve it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The purpose of introducing 2 new variables is to reduce the situation to the one you know how to solve (with only $u_x$ or $u_y$). As for $V$, looks like it is just the new name for $u$, which makes no sense to me, so just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to solve the problem is to use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

If we let $x \mapsto x(s), y \mapsto y(s)$, we get

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds} u(x(s), y(s)) &= u_{x} \cdot \frac{dx}{ds} + u_{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{ds} \quad \text{(by chain rule)} \\
&= u_{x} \cdot 1 + u_{y} \cdot 1 \quad \text{(from our PDE)} \\
&= u \quad \text{(from our PDE)}
\end{align}

and so equating, we find

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{ds} &= 1 \implies dy = ds \\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= 1 \implies dx = ds \implies dx = dy \quad (1) \\
\frac{du}{ds} &= u \implies \frac{du}{dx} = u \quad (2) \\
\end{align}

Now, $(1)$ gives

$$y(x) = x + y_{0}$$

and $(2)$ gives

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{u} &= dx \\
\implies \ln u &= x + f(y_{0}) \\
\implies u &= f(y_{0}) e^{x} \\
\implies u &= f(y - x)e^{x}
\end{align}

You can check by differentiation that this satisfies the PDE.